# Duplicate the same page on two monitors in VS2010 (so not exactly split view)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm wondering if it's possible to duplicate the same page on two monitors. So sorta like split view, but instead of just split in the middle have it duplicate in a new window.

Is this possible in VS2010?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click Window, New Window to create a second document window for the same file.

You can then undock the new window and move it to a second monitor.

Comment: Thanks! I've been wanting this for a while now :)

Comment: Of course, I didn't yesterday because StackOverflow makes me wait at least 10 minutes to mark it as accepted.